# Making a 2D array of children elements

Tags: c++, visual-c++, abstract-class, chess

I'm trying to create a chess engine, so I made a Board class (only showing the h file because the implementation is pretty straight forward):

```
class Board {
private:
    Piece* board[SIZE][SIZE];
    bool turn;
public:
    Board();
    Piece* getBoard() const;
    void printBoard() const;
};
```

The idea is to make a 2D array filled with different pieces.
Obviously, I made a Piece class as well (a parent class to all other pieces):

```
class Piece {
protected:
    bool color;
    int PosX;
    int PosY;
public:
    Piece(const bool c, const int x, const int y);
    ~Piece();
    virtual int tryMove(int toX, int toY, Board &board) const = 0;
    virtual char toChar() const = 0;
}
```

I made an EmptyPiece class to try and initialize the array, but I just can't figure out how to fill the array with those pieces.

the h file for EmptyPiece:

```
class EmptyPiece : protected Piece {
public:
    EmptyPiece(const bool c, const int x, const int y);
    char toChar() const;
    int tryMove(int toX, int toY, Board& board) const;
};
```

and this is how I'm trying to initialize the array:

```
Board::Board()
{
    turn = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            board[i][j] = EmptyPiece(0, i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

which results in an error:

```
E0413   no suitable conversion function from "EmptyPiece" to "Piece *" exists
```

Comment: Typo?  `board[i][j] = EmptyPiece(0, i, j);` -> `board[i][j] = new EmptyPiece(0, i, j);`

Comment: @RichardCritten it doesn't work either.
"conversion to base class Piece is not allowed"

Comment: Please see [conversion to inaccessible base class is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062562/conversion-to-inaccessible-base-class-is-not-allowed)

Comment: @user6394139 change the `protected` inheritance to `public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the right side of the following statement:

```
board[i][j] = EmptyPiece(0, i, j);
```

`EmptyPiece(0, i, j)` created a temporary object with type `EmptyPiece`, which is also convertible to type `Piece`. But the left side requires a variable of type `Piece*`, i.e. a **pointer** to a `Piece` object. In general, you can't assign a variable of type `T` to another variable of type `T*`.

You can fix it with the following version:

```
board[i][j] = new EmptyPiece(0, i, j);
```

But you need to remember to `delete` the objects you `new`'ed.